# I want to stop page reload on link button click for download

Tags: html, .net, ajax

I want to avoid page reload or postback on a page. When i click on the download button it redirect to new page for file download but at the same time its reload the page which i don't want. I had also used ajax for not doing postback but its not working and the page is getting reload.

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upd1" runat="server">        
        <ContentTemplate>             
       <asp:ListView ID="Formlist" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
       <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />    
        </ul>                
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li class="list-group-item">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" Visible='<%# Eval("F_Path")==""?false:true %>'  CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("F_Path") %>' runat="server" OnClick = "DownloadFile_Final"><i class="fontseting fa fa-download" title="Download" > </i></asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkView" Visible='<%# Eval("F_Path")==""?false:true %>'  CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("F_Path") %>' runat="server" OnClick = "ViewFile"><i class="fontseting fa fa-eye" title="View" > </i></asp:LinkButton>
                <p style="text-align:left;color:#53ae7a;font-weight:bold; text-transform: capitalize;"> <%#Eval("F_NAME") %> </p>
                <p style="text-align:left;color:#2c2d31; font-size:12px; font-weight:100"> <%#Eval("F_DESC") %> </p>

            </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>

 </ContentTemplate>

 </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: `OnClick = "this.preventDefault();DownloadFile_Final"`

Comment: no its not working it showing complication error in it

Comment: Write some jQuery at start of the page: `$("body").on("click","a", function(e){e.preventDefault();});`